# Find exact match of variable within multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to write a bash code which should get a variable and search within multiple arrays.  For example:

```
$var = site.com
```

And my arrays are:

```
array1=(test world myword something bla my.site.com)
array=(google facebook stackoverflow site.com)
array=(music eating video site.com.dev)
```

The code that I'm trying to run and unfortunately not working is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ${array1[*]} =~ "$var" ]]; then
   echo "it's array1"
elif [[ ${array2[*]} =~ "$var" ]]; then 
   echo "it's array2"
elif [[ ${array3[*]} =~ "$var" ]]; then
   echo "it's array3"
fi
```

The problem here is that it even it return the same array for "site.com", "my.site.com" and "site.com.dev".

What's missing here and how I should write it properly?

Comment: This would be much more efficient if you built your arrays with associative ones with your lookup values as keys in the first place.

Comment: That is, `declare -A array1=( [test]=1 [world]=1 [myword]=1 [something]=1 [my.site.com]=1 )`; then you can just check whether `[[ ${array1["$var"]} ]]` is true.

Comment: ...trying to flatten your arrays into strings and run regexes on those strings in both slow and buggy (it'll find substrings, not just exact matches; and the single string means you can't distinguish between one entry containing "two words" and an entry named "two" followed by a separate entry named "words").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=~` is an unanchored regex -- when the right side is quoted, it becomes a substring search. `${array[*]}` assembles a string by combining all the entries in your array with the first character in `IFS` (a space by default) between them. Thus, `[[ ${array[*]} =~ "$var" ]]` is flattening your array into a string, and doing a substring search on that string.

`site.com` is a substring of `my.site.com` and of `site.com.dev`, so it's expected for it to match.

If you want an efficient, exact-match-only search, invert your arrays to be associative rather than numerically-indexed, and do a key lookup for each.

That is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Needs bash 4.0 or newer" >&2; exit 1;; esac

var=site.com

declare -A array1=( [test]=1 [world]=1 [myword]=1 [something]=1 [my.site.com]=1 )
declare -A array2=( [google]=1 [facebook]=1 [stackoverflow]=1 [site.com]=1 )
declare -A array3=( [music]=1 [eating]=1 [video]=1 [site.com.dev]=1 )

if [[ ${array1["$var"]} ]]; then echo "It's array1"
elif [[ ${array2["$var"]} ]]; then echo "It's array2"
elif [[ ${array3["$var"]} ]]; then echo "It's array3"
else echo "Not found"
fi
```